# Extend Java class or provide a static help class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, static

For example: I have to use the date class in my project, but i need for example easy methods to add minutes to a Date etc. Should I:

Make a static class with methods like `public static Date addToDate(Date date, int timeToAdd)`

Make a class MyDate that extends Date and provide methods like `public Date add(int duration)`

As i was looking into this issue i got interested into what the better approach might be in general, especially concerning classes from the standard library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go for the first approach. One of the things I hate of some OOP degenerations, is that sometimes useless classes proliferate - often it's a perfectionist whim that brings to an escalation of bizarre classes where there are two methods and nothing really significant, and this brings to a bunch of useless code.

Just make a `DateUtils` class, and always check the Java Runtime doesn't already provide something similar.

Comment: +1 for DateUtils class suggestion. In simple situations I think it's the better approach in order to avoid proliferation of classes.

Comment: Allright thanks; I have to say it's not alway easy to say: now I stop making more classes, there is no exact limit what i still can put in a class and where i need a special class for.

Comment: You welcome. You are right, but there's a kind of way to see if it's worth making a new derived class, it is not so 'strict' but it can help you... If the class has to store some additional data (in a new field) then you may need a derived class. In other words, if the new class has to retain some 'status'. In this case since the transformations are stateless, then... you know. See also @0verbose answer. :)

Comment: There's no difference in class/method count if you create a DateUtil class to store your Date methods; another argument against the first choice is that, if you need an object with the said methods, you are hiding dependencies if you write them as a static method.

Answer (score 2):

People often suggest to use composition instead of inheritance. Anyway there are cases in which inheritance fit better. 
You have said :

> I need for example easy methods to add minutes to a Date etc.

If you really need simple methods, and no additional fields are needed to store additional properties, then follow @Giacomo approach, using the a class DateUtils like he suggested, with static methods that can perform the operations you need.

If you need to store additional data to the Date object, then consider using a class to do so. If this is the situation, I disagree with @thasc, because even if generally using composition instead of inheritance could be a good practice, create an extended version of the Date class allow you to use your ExtendedDateObject directly in method that requires a Date parameter.

Comment: Thank you; and without the ability to use an ExtendedDate object as parameter i would not have doubted. The "store additional properties" sounds like a good rule of thumbs, thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from Date is asking for trouble. There is enough confusion with java.util.Date, java.util.Timestamp, java.sql.Date, without adding to the complexity with your own subclasses. Definitely go with the static method approach.

Be aware it's likely some of the functions you may need are already implemented in [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/index.html). If your instructor allows it then you may be better off using that library instead of following either of the options in the question.

Comment: there is no DataTime class in javaSE

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second choice, for the following reason

- I see more classes as a less dominant problem, vs too many static methods. Where to begin and where to stop? Are 3 methods enough to create a subclass?

You could name it sth. like DateWithMinuteHandling, to make naming confusions less likely

Answer (score -1):

Consider using Joda-Time library for date/time manipulation.